# Boost Multiprecision float128: std::exp error: 'no matching function for call'

Tags: c++, boost

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

/*
Boost Lib: https://www.boost.org
added compiler options:
                        -fext-numeric-literals
*/
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>
using namespace boost::multiprecision;

int main(){
    float128 x = 34235235.00090912892709;
    float128 z = std::exp(x);
    std::cout<< z;

return 0;
}
```

Gives the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘exp(boost::multiprecision::float128&)’
```

Boost should be able to use any C++ std lib function; where is my mistake?

Comment: Boost can not extend the `std` namespace with its own overloads. Doing so leads to *undefined behavior*. You must use the explicit Boost functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  so should I write my own exp function? or what should I do?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude just `exp(x)` will do since ADL kicks in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Boost should be able to use any C++ std lib function

That's exactly your mistake. You can cast the `float128` type to a double and pass that to `std::exp`, but as you probably use the multiprecision library for a reason, this might not be a good idea. Instead, call the function provided by boost itself:

```
const auto z = boost::multiprecision::exp(x);
```

You might want to omit `boost::multiprecision::` and rely upon ADL or the using directive in your example. For this to work, it might be necessary to add the `-lquadmath` and/or `-fext-numeric-literals` linker flag (thanks to @JHBonarius for pointing that out).

Comment: and add possibly `-fext-numeric-literals`. But `#include <boost/multiprecision/number.hpp>` is not necessary, as it is added in the header of float128.hpp.

Comment: @JHBonarius Thanks for the hint, I'll include that in the answer.